# Angular directive only work with ng prefix

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have following code which works fine

**directive**

```
payrollWeb.directive('ngEnter', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

**View**

```
<input type="password" ng-enter="login()" ng-model="autPass">
```

But I don;t want to declare my directive with ng prefix as it is not recommended. But as soon as I change it to anything alse it doesn't work.

Ex:

```
payrollWeb.directive('prEnter', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

and,

```
<input type="password" pr-enter="login()" ng-model="autPass">
```

Any clue?

Ish

Comment: Typo, copy-paste issue :) `scope.$eval(attrs.prEnter);`, marking for closure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
```

should be:

```
scope.$eval(attrs.prEnter);
```